# Erratic behavior of thermocouple input

Tags: data, thermocouple, plc

I am reading temperature from a K thermocouple on a PLC which is then forwarded to a trending software to see the data on a graph. The thermocouple is in a water trough/reservoir. In fact, there are 3 thermocouples in the trough located at 3 corners. One of them is giving erratic data as shown in the attached snapshots (blue trend) [image: Trend]. [image: Trend 2]

To check if the problem lies in the thermocouple or on the PLC connector, I disconnected the probe from the PLC and connected it to a portable datalogger. The datalogger showed consistent data (no random drops) so I am wondering if the connector is faulty. But then again is the connector really faulty if two other probes hooked to it are showing consistent data. Has anyone ever come across something like this?

Not sure if this helps but there is a water pipe pushing relatively colder water into the trough where the probe in question is located (but then again I can see this water pipe affecting the temp by 5-6 degrees C but not by a whopping 20 degrees C)

Comment: Is there a serial port or a similar driver near by? Does the PLC drive relays or other high power peripherals?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the thermocouples (TCs) around, into different positions?  Does the problem remain on that position, or on the same TC?  Are the TC connected in parallel, or each independently being sampled?  Parallel configuration will need resistors to average the TCs.

Comment: Yes there are serial ports and relays in that panel. But the thermocouple wires I am using are shielded (except ofcourse the 1 or 2 inches where they land on the connector). But if these devices were interfering with the TC signal, wouldn't they interfere with both?

Answer (score 2):

As Aaron has said I the comments, I think this is a situation for some old fashioned troubleshooting. One of your devices or connections is probably bad. Swap which thermocouple is connected to which PLC input, swap the transmitters around (assuming they're not built into the thermocouple or PLC). Swap the thermocouple locations. Wiggle the connectors. Take the bad thermocouple out and place it next to another thermocouple and see if they read the same. Etc, etc.

As you swap things around, you almost certainly find that the problem follows one device, connector, or configuration. From there it should be fairly easy to figure out what to replace or fix.

Comment: I moved the TC input to another I/O point on the connector. Will have to wait and see if that improves the signal. But looking at the distorted signal, and as Lior Bilia mentioned, it does appear that high powered devices are interfering with the signal.

Comment: I'm not saying it couldn't be electrical noise, but that chart doesn't look like it to me. See how it's spiking to a consistent low value? That reeks of a bad connection, or a device "dropping out" occasionally. In my experience, electrical noise is more random. Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(electronics)#/media/File:Pink.noise.png